# Remote access to MysqlDB

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

I want to connect to a MySql DB on VM on the network from the command line. I'm trying to use telnet user@192.xxxx 3306 but I get the follwoing message `Name or service not known`. Ive read that I should probably go at the cnf file but I would like to know why and get some confirmation if that is the correct thing to do in this situation.

Comment: Generally on a default install of MySQL the server only listens on localhost. If you would like to open it up then editing my.cnf would be appropriate.

See: bind-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`telnet` doesn't allow a username in the parameters, it just takes the name or address of the server. The server will prompt for a username and password if you connect to the normal login port. MySQL uses a binary protocol, it doesn't use a textual login.

So the command should be:

```
telnet 192.xxxx 3306
```